# how socket() and bind() behave?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, network-programming

I have some questions about C++ socket programming. please help to dig deep, and help to correct, if the way I asked is wrong.

1. Are there one file descriptor per each port in OS level.
2. How do multiple ports use same network interface? is it switching like
   threads in processor? so, if number of using ports increase, can it be
   delayed data for specific port?
3. What happens in OS level when creates a socket? does is create any reference to IO file descriptors?
4. Then what happens in OS level when calls bind(). how it interconnect socket and NIC address?
5. What happens when use reusable socket? How multiple sockets bind to one port? do those switching on one port like threads?
6. when sending or receiving without bind() to specific address or port?
   How and what is the logic OS select a address and a port.

Comment: This is probably to broad for the format here. You are asking about implementation details of sockets, which can vary from system to system. It might be good if you pick up a networking book to understand what a *port* really is in the protocol you use.

Comment: @ David Rodríguez - dribeas: I'm looking for the details of Linux or Unix environment.I tried some reference books read online, but those are so messy. I need some simple idea how these systems works. I think peoples who are doing socket programming should have a idea what are those right?

Comment: These systems are complicated, so I wouldn't expect "a simple idea how linux networking works".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there one file descriptor per each port in OS level.

No. If you're a server accepting connections on a listening socket you might have 10,000 file descriptors all referring to the same local port number.

> How do multiple ports use same network interface? is it switching like threads in processor? so, if number of using ports increase, can it be delayed data for specific port?

Too complex to answer here.

> What happens in OS level when creates a socket? does is create any reference to IO file descriptors?

They are very similar things, in some operating systems they are even the same thing. One refers to a socket, the other refers to an open file.

> Then what happens in OS level when calls bind().

A port and IP address are allocated to the socket. The IP address can be 0.0.0.0. If the specified port was zero, the system chooses one for you from the free ports.

> how it interconnect socket and NIC address?

See above.

> What happens when use reusable socket?

There is no such thing as a 'reusable socket'. Are you talking about reusing the *port?*

> when sending or receiving without bind() to specific address or port? How and what is the logic OS select a address and a port.

A `bind()` is executed behind the scenes if you haven't already executed one yourself. So the same rules apply for `bind()` as above.

Comment: thank you so much for the direct answers. actually I read lot and now have some idea. here I mention about re use of port as socket option. here I got here answer. http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya That's what it does in TCP. For UDP it's a completely different story.

Answer (score 3):

You would be hard-pressed to find a more influential network programming text than the "bible" of sockets, W Richard Stevens: [Unix Network Programming](http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv12e.html). Socket programming is  NOT something that comes to you overnight, so don't expect it to. It is a discipline, plain and simple. And, like all disciplines, it needs to be honed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read on socket programming, what you are asking is basic concepts, you should understand terminologies like servers, clients, TCP, UDP, local host, remote hosts.
socket() creates an interface between the process and the transport layer, it creates and tells the characteristics of the socket.
bind() binds the socket to your local address.
you can check man pages 1 or 2 and you will find a comprehensive answer.